# Please explain temp table in sql?

Tags: sql, temp-tables, temp

Can anyone explain this to me ?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RH') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #RH 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TERM') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TERM 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CLRIS') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #CLAERIS
```

What does this code mean

```
OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CLAERIS')
```

Is it mandatory to mention this?

Comment: Reading the documentation always helps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) OBJECT_ID() returns the internal ID from the sys.objects catalog.

Basically the code checks if the temporary table exists and if yes, the table gets dropped.

Comment: Can you explain the Object_ID() in detail? Why do we use it?